# C++ CPU Graph inside window

Tags: c++, graph, real-time, cpu

I'm starting a project in C++ and I want to create a graph of the CPU like found in the task manager.

Should I be looking for a graphing or display library?
Should I investigate using OpenGL to display a real time graph?

I'm looking for the most elegant solution to get a graph display inside a window.

I looked around and could not even find out what the task manager uses to display it's CPU and memory graphs, and I don't want to jump in and start using and learning the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like Task Manager doesn't update the screen all that often (once a second or so). That means efficiency isn't really a huge problem for it. GDI is probably the easiest way to do the drawing, and will almost certainly still give perfectly adequate performance.

If you want to keep your life as easy as possible, you might consider a library that already implements what you want/need, such as [one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17564/Simple-Performance-Chart) or [another](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14075/High-speed-Charting-Control) on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15694/Realtime-Chart-and-Graph-in-One).